# Mails not received on Gmail Email ID: saket.mishra@atlascorps.org through PHP Mail Function

Tags: php, email, gmail, sendmail

I am using following code to send email whosoever registers.

```
$recmail = 'saket.mishra@atlascorps.org'; // address you want the form mailed to
    $sub = "Atlas Corps Questionnaire"; //subject of email that is sent
    $mess = "Hello, Please fill a questionnaire at following link. ";

    $headers = "From: Atlas Corps Family Tree  < info@atlascorps.org > \n" . 
               "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
               "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";

    mail($recmail,$sub,$mess,$headers);
```

My saket.mishra@atlascorps.org is a valid Gmail Account.
But i am not receiving any emails here.
I have checked all my setting of gmail properly. 
No forwarding and filtering is applied.

where as my other Gmail Account: saket.me@gmail.com
Is receiving all the emails through this website.

Please help, as all my customers will have the **@atlascorps.org** email account on Gmail.

**On Email Logs of the server, following message is there**

```
Return-path: <>
Envelope-to: atlascorpsadmin@p3plcpnl0096.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
Delivery-date: Tue, 23 Sep 2014 08:56:11 -0700
Received: from mailnull by p3plcpnl0096.prod.phx3.secureserver.net with local (Exim 4.82)
    id 1XWSRn-0003Fc-2A
    for atlascorpsadmin@p3plcpnl0096.prod.phx3.secureserver.net; Tue, 23 Sep 2014 08:56:11 -0700
X-Failed-Recipients: saket.mishra@atlascorps.org
Auto-Submitted: auto-replied
From: Mail Delivery System <Mailer-Daemon@p3plcpnl0096.prod.phx3.secureserver.net>
To: atlascorpsadmin@p3plcpnl0096.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
Subject: Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender
Message-Id: <E1XWSRn-0003Fc-2A@p3plcpnl0096.prod.phx3.secureserver.net>
Date: Tue, 23 Sep 2014 08:56:11 -0700

This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  saket.mishra@atlascorps.org


------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------

Return-path: <atlascorpsadmin@p3plcpnl0096.prod.phx3.secureserver.net>
Received: from atlascorpsadmin by p3plcpnl0096.prod.phx3.secureserver.net with local (Exim 4.82)
    (envelope-from <atlascorpsadmin@p3plcpnl0096.prod.phx3.secureserver.net>)
    id 1XWSRm-0003FX-Vo
    for saket.mishra@atlascorps.org; Tue, 23 Sep 2014 08:56:11 -0700
To: saket.mishra@atlascorps.org
Subject: Atlas Corps Questionnaire
X-PHP-Script: atlascorps.org/globe/send_link.php for 122.176.7.34
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 209330:send_link.php
From: Atlas Corps Family Tree  < info@atlascorps.org > 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Message-Id: <E1XWSRm-0003FX-Vo@p3plcpnl0096.prod.phx3.secureserver.net>

Hello
```

Comment: Check your mail server logs.

Comment: Hi the above is my log file

Comment: That's incomplete and mostly unreadable. To post content like that, edit your question, don't try to put it in comments.

Comment: @Synchro, i have edited the question...
Can you please help me!

Comment: That's a bounce, not log output, and it's pretty useless because it doesn't give a reason for the bounce (this is a common problem with exim). The logs will have more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you check your DNS settings and mainly the SPF record you have. If you go to the kitterman tool for [SPF checks](http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html), you'll see that your `SPF` record appears to be invalid:

```
Input accepted, querying now...
evaluating v=spf1 a mx ptr include:secureserver.net ~all ...
Results - PermError SPF Permanent Error: Too many DNS lookups
```

My guess is that google is sometimes failing to resolve all `secureserver.net` records, therefore it's bouncing back some messages. Instead of having `include:secureserver.net` try removing it and setting an `MX` record that points to your server. The `SPF` record is set to allow all `MX` records to send emails, so that should work fine.

Also, I would suggest using a mailer library such as [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), which is quite easier to maintain and debug than the default php `mailer` function. Here is a snippet code, which can give you a head start:

```
require_once '/path/to/swift-mailer/lib/swift_init.php';

// Create the message
// http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setFrom('info@atlascorps.org', 'Atlas Corps Family Tree');
$message->setTo('saket.mishra@atlascorps.org');
$message->setContentType('text/html');
$message->setCharset('iso-8850-1');
$message->setSubject('Atlas Corps Questionnaire');
$message->setBody('<html><head></head><body>Hello, Please fill a questionnaire at following <a href="http://domain.com/link.php?time='.time().'">link</a>.</body></html>');


// Create the Transport
// http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#the-smtp-transport
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('localhost', 25);

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$mailer->send($message);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your mail server (exim) will have log files, probably in `/var/log/mail/log` or nearby, and this will have more detail about why your deliveries are failing. Unfortunately the bounce you posted doesn't contain any useful information.

Expanding on tftd's answer:

[RFC4408 imposes a limit](http://www.openspf.org/RFC_4408#mech-mx) of 10 lookups. There's a good analysis of SPF lookup counting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14262788/333340). The killer clause in your SPF is `mx` because it lists 5 mail servers. secureserver.net's SPF record only contains ip4 clauses, so will not incur any additional lookups. In the SPF you really don't need `ptr` (and you don't have a DNS entry for that anyway), so that will save a lookup, and since your `a` record is only a single IP, it would be a good idea to list that explicitly first. I'd suggest you alter your SPF to this to minimise lookup count:

```
v=spf1 ip4:192.186.207.194 include:secureserver.net mx a ~all
```

I've left the `a` in there in case you change your IP and forget to update this record...

All that said, this won't necessarily mean that your SPF is preventing deliveries, since a mail server will stop checking check SPF entries when it finds a match, and if it matches one of your MXs that will be well before the lookup limit.

Comment: Hey, Where to change this MX? I didn't found any mail/log such directory path on my server...

Comment: It's in your DNS, and you need them there.